# Is shared hosting appropriate for a forums site, or do forums need something better?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, forms

My website attracts fairly medium amount of traffic. Does a forum need something stronger?

I think choosing shared hosting for a blog site will depend on how large it is and other factors. is it the same for forums too. What can be other hosting option in case shared hosting is not an ideal option

Answer (score 1):

both blog and forum are pretty much similar, because much of backend information is pulled from the database. What your core focus should be, what is being served on the forum. Will there be alot of downloading and uploading of graphic and other files? Will there be a huge amount of traffic. If there is a huge amount of traffic, you should consider upgrading your hosting account to something else different and adjusting the hosting account type as you grow.

Here is a list of hosting account type that you can grow as your website grows:

- Share Hosting
- VPS Hosting
- Dedicated hosting

Most people nowadays, use cloud base hosting. This type of hosting aloud you to adapt to website growth and increase space, bandwidth, and memories at the click of a button.

Hope that helps answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the database server and the web server in your considerations, because it's about how many web pages you need to serve, and how many database hits you need to do to generate and serve those pages and manage forum content.

So it could could be you only need a small web server, but a bigger database server for example.  That might be the case where you have a smaller community who's extremely active in posting.

Really since it's hard to know the correct answer, but with what I've said above in mind, you're better off choosing a hosting service that allows you to change up and down your server sizes.  Start small, see how the performance is.  If it is fine, don't change anything.  If you see your database showing some load issues, up your database machine.  Maybe it needs more memory, maybe it needs more CPU, maybe both.  If your web server is showing problems, up it.

You won't know for sure until you try it.